# iTunes Connect - Invalid Bundle -> Bitcode Issue

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, bitcode

I have a problem with my build becoming invalid in iTunes Connect. I have a workspace consisting of app project, library project and cocoa pods project in it. My cocoa pods has only KeychainSwift and GoogleMaps in it.

From iTunes Connect I get the reason described as

> Invalid Bundle - This app includes files that were built with bitcode enabled but without doing an Archive or Install build, possibly from a library or framework that was imported but not built as part of the project. Full bitcode content is only generated in an Archive or Install build.

I have bit code enabled in settings and also do Product->Archive but it somehow does not work. Am I doing something wrong is it because of the libraries? Is there a way to find out which one is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of different things I tried one seems to be the solution for my problem: The location of my own library copied to the app project needs to be Location: "Relative to Group" (not "Absolute Path"). Now it was accepted by iTunes Connect.